# Finding lowest two minimum values and finding difference between the two in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction table where I have to find the first and second date of transaction of every customer. Finding first date is very simple where I can use MIN() func to find the first date but the second and in particular finding the difference between the two is getting very challenging and somehow I am not able to find out any feasible way:

```
select a.customer_id, a.transaction_date, a.Row_Count2
from ( select
       transaction_date as transaction_date,
       reference_no as customer_id,
       row_number() over (partition by reference_no 
                          ORDER BY reference_no, transaction_date) AS Row_Count2
       from transaction_detail 
     ) a
where  a.Row_Count2 < 3
ORDER BY a.customer_id, a.transaction_date, a.Row_Count2
```

Gives me this :

[image]

What I want is , following columns:

||CustomerID|| ||FirstDateofPurchase|| ||SecondDateofPuchase|| ||Diff. b/w Second & First Date ||

Comment: Please explain the results that you want.  The query seems to answer your question.

Comment: ||CustomerID||   ||First Date of Purchase || || SubsequentSecond Date of Purchase|| || Diff. b/w Second & First Date ||

Comment: Are the results not what you want? If not, it seems like you could remove the reference_no from the order by to fix the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions LEAD/LAG to return results you are looking for

First try to find all the leading dates by reference number using LEAD, generate row number for each row using your original logic. You can then do difference on dates for row number value 1 row from the result set.

Ex (I'm not excluding same day transactions and treating them as separate and generating row number based on result set from your query above, you can easily change the sql below to consider these as one and remove them so that you get next date as second date):

```
declare @tbl table(reference_no int, transaction_date datetime)
insert into @tbl
select 1000, '2018-07-11'
UNION ALL
select 1001, '2018-07-12'
UNION ALL
select 1001, '2018-07-12'
UNIOn ALL
select 1001, '2018-07-13'
UNIOn ALL
select 1002, '2018-07-11'
UNIOn ALL
select 1002, '2018-07-15'

select customer_id, transaction_date as firstdate, 
transaction_date_next seconddate, 
datediff(day, transaction_date,  transaction_date_next) diff_in_days
from
(
    select reference_no as customer_id, transaction_date, 
    lead(transaction_date) over (partition by reference_no 
                                   order by transaction_date) transaction_date_next,
    row_number() over (partition by reference_no ORDER BY transaction_date) AS Row_Count
    from @tbl
) src
where Row_Count = 1
```

Comment: I am not aware of Lead/Lag func in SQL and still do not understand them but somehow your solution worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT td.customer_id, MIN(ca.transaction_date), MAX(ca.transaction_date),
       DATEDIFF(day, MIN(ca.transaction_date), MAX(ca.transaction_date))
FROM transaction_detail td
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 2 *
             FROM transaction_detail
             WHERE customer_id = td.customer_id
             ORDER BY transaction_date) ca
GROUP BY td.customer_id
```